# Can we extract date from the name of source file and add it to a db column using talend

Tags: talend

So if I have a source file containing 10 columns and my target contains 11 columns and the extra column is of type date . The source file contains a name like 'cust20201212' now I wish to extract only the date part and add this to my target table column in the date type column. Is it possible to achieve this using talend. I just want to extract the date as 2020-12-12 and 2020-12-01 and store it in the date column of oracle table.
Can we use tregexextract in this scenario?

Answer (score 1):

You need firstly to get your Filename in the flow, or in a variable . Do you have it in a context variable, or does it come from a tFileList ?
If you have a tFileList in your job , you can access it with global Variable
: `((String)globalMap.get("tFileList_1_CURRENT_FILE"))`

When you have this filename, you have to parse your filename to extract the data :

```
TalendDate.parseDate("yyyyMMdd",StringHandling.LEFT(StringHandling.RIGHT(*PLACE_HERE_FILENAME*,12),8))
```

`StringHandling.RIGHT` get the last part of your filename (8 chars + extension (4 chars) = 12)
`StringHandling.LEFT` gets you the first 8 chars of this expression (20201201)

```
TalendDate.parseDate convert the string representing your date to an actual date.
```

Then you can pass this new data to your oracle db.

Comment: Hi , So can i map tfilelist to tfileinputdelimted with iterate and then tfileinputdelimited to tmap with main and giving it tfileouputdelimted and then feed this outputfile to db as an input?

Comment: you could have tfileList>tfileinput>tmap>tdboutput. No need to have a tFileOutputDelimited in between.

Comment: Alright and the schema to be set as a single column ,right?

Comment: this date will be a new column (type 'Date') in your output schema

Comment: Hey its giving me an error on this syntax TalendDate.parseDate("yyyyMMdd",StringHandling.LEFT(StringHandling.RIGHT(*PLACE_HERE_FILENAME*,12),8)) ,once i place the filename there its throwing an error